# How to setup YII to use a different driver than PDO

Tags: yii2

I am not finding a instructions on how to run a Yii project on a different driver than PDO.
Our configuration is similar to the following:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279984/how-i-can-connect-to-oracle-database-with-yii2/50283791#50283791) answer solves your problem.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam that answer is about connecting to different DBMS but it still uses PDO for those connections.

Comment: The yii's DB component is implemented using PDO. If you have to use other driver you have 2 options. You can override the `yii\db\Connection`, `yii\db\Transaction` and `yii\db\DataReader` with your own implementations. Or you can wrap the other driver in class with same interface as PDO and set the `yii\db\Connection::$pdoClass` property to use your wrapper.

Comment: yeah @MichalHynčica you are right just overlooked that PDO in first line

Comment: Michal Hynčica it looks like you have answered the question and how can I mark that you have answered the question.

Comment: @sdxbp you cannot accept the comment as answer. I've only posted that as comment, because i've never implemented that myself. If you manage to make a working solution you can post it as answer yourself for others who might be looking for the solution.